# How to Handle a Long List of Tabs

Tags: javascript

I have a list of tabs that are dynamically generated:

```
<ul>
    <li>Tab #1</li>
    <li>Tab #2</li>
    <li>Tab #3</li>
    <li>Tab #4</li>
    <li>Tab #5</li>
    <!-- ...up to #N -->
</ul>
```

There could be anywhere from 2 to infinity tabs. The design team wants the last tab to say `More v[down arrow]` and turn into a drop down containing the remaining tabs if and only if the width of the tabs exceeds the space allotted them. Upon selection of one of the tabs in the drop down, the `More v` text will change to that of the tab selected so the user will know which tab they are on.

```
Tab #1 | Tab #2 | Tab #3 | Tab #4 | More v
                                    Tab #5
                                    Tab #6
                                    Tab #7
                                    Tab #8
                                    Tab #9
```

While I can definitely think of a couple of ways to handle this offhand, **are there any libraries that can handle this for me** or **are there any techniques or general guidelines you'd like to share?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think if you have infinity tabs you're in trouble.

Comment: I guess by "infinity" I meant "20-ish".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this, I came up with my own solution since there were some pretty specific business reqs.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshpauljohnson/U3vV7/6/